# Could not calculate build plan

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have seen many problems, that can solve this kind of problem, and i have tried most of them and i am stuck for around 2 days now.I am using ubuntu 18.04 and java version 1.8.0. I am getting following error. ->

> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6

I have tried following things,but none of them worked ->

1. Deleting .m2 folder and build again
2. force update project
3. Adding Dependency Manually by downloading jar file

This is my POM.xml file

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>VERSION</modelVersion>
<groupId>GROUP</groupId>
<artifactId>ARTIFACT</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>MAVEN</name>

<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jackson.version>2.6.2</jackson.version>
    <spring-boot.version>1.2.6.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <filter.name>DEV</filter.name>
    <jersey.version>1.9</jersey.version>
    <base.directory>${basedir}</base.directory>
</properties>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>local</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <filter.name>DEV</filter.name>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <filter.name>DEV</filter.name>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>prod</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <filter.name>PROD</filter.name>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.kencochrane.raven</groupId>
        <artifactId>raven-log4j2</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.spullara.mustache.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.flipkart.zjsonpatch</groupId>
        <artifactId>zjsonpatch</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.bitwalker</groupId>
        <artifactId>UserAgentUtils</artifactId>
        <version>1.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <type>pom.lastUpdated</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <!-- <filters> <filter>${basedir}/src/main/resources/ENV-${filter.name}/application.properties</filter> 
        </filters> -->
    <finalName>SPRING</finalName>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <debuglevel>source,lines</debuglevel>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <archive>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <environment>prod</environment>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-svn-revision-number-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-svn-revision-number-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <entries>
                        <entry>
                            <prefix>svn</prefix>
                        </entry>
                    </entries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-timestamp</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create-timestamp</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <format>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}</format>
                    <items>
                        <item>timestamp</item>
                    </items>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>

    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: sounds like network issues..furthermore are you doing a spring-boot application? If yes than your setup is completely wrong...

Comment: @khmarbaise, yes it's spring boot application. how can i make it work? i am new to maven and spring

Comment: @khmarbaise, it was working on windows with same configuration, i just need to import the project from git and that's it, now i am in ubuntu idk why it's throwing this error? I have also tried proxy settings inside settings.xml file, but idk what to put inside the value of proxy, as i am not using any proxy server,so that was also not worked.

Comment: If it is a spring boot project I would recommend first to read the documentation how to work with Spring Boot applications in relationship with Maven and recommend to start with the most recent versions and not so old versions something like this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/...BTW: are you behind a proxy ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, there is not proxy server, i am using localhost.